# How to build the following neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

How to build the following network?

```
Implement a neural network for a generator with the following layers:

A fully connected layer with 100 neurons;
The batch normalization layer;
ReLU activation function;
A fully connected layer with 100 neurons;
The batch normalization layer;
ReLU activation function;
The output layer.
```

Quite don't understand what is output layer. Does this code resemble the description?

```
nn.Sequential( # NN architecture, where the modules modify the data sequentially
            nn.Linear(n_inputs, 100),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1)
            nn.ReLU(), # Activation function 
            nn.Linear(100, 100),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1)
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(100, n_outputs) # Another Linear transformation
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code resembles the description for the most part. There are two things to note:

- Since you are using **nn.BatchNorm2d()**, I am going to assume you are working with images (or 2D data). The argument you pass to **nn.BatchNorm2d()** will depend on the number of channels in the images you intend to feed to your network. Since you are using **1**, the number of channels in each image that you feed to the network should be **1**.
- The output layer simply represents the last layer of neurons that produces an output for a neural network. In your case, that is a linear layer with ReLU activation. You don't need to add the output layer as a separate linear layer.

You can find the required code below:

```py
nn.Sequential( # NN architecture, where the modules modify the data sequentially
            nn.Linear(n_inputs, 100),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1)
            nn.ReLU(), # Activation function 
            nn.Linear(100, 100),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1)
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
```

Comment: But maybe the last layer ***is*** meant to have `n_outputs` neurons.

Comment: Yup, maybe it is. Without a specification for the size (or type), it's hard to say.